# Storing array information into c++ vector has an "Access violation reading location"

Tags: c++

When I try to load vertices and triangle face information into a vector, I get the "Access violation reading location."

Here is my code for loading:

```
    struct TriangleData {
    PointEntry  *ptidx[3];
    bool    deleted;
};

    class PointEntry {
    public:
        float   x, y, z;
        std::vector<TriangleData*>  trianglelist;
        friend bool operator < (const PointEntry&a, const PointEntry&b) { return (a.x < b.x) || ((a.x == b.x) && (a.y < b.y)) || ((a.x == b.x) && (a.y == b.y) && (a.z < b.z)); };
        friend bool operator == (const PointEntry&a, const PointEntry&b) { return !(a<b) && !(b<a); }
        friend bool operator != (const PointEntry&a, const PointEntry&b) { return !(a == b); }
};

    for (int i = 0; i < num_triangles; i++) {
            PointEntry tmp;
            PointEntry *p;
            for (int j = 0; j<3; j++) {
            tmp.x = verts[3 * indicies[3 * i + j] + 0];
            tmp.y = verts[3 * indicies[3 * i + j] + 1];
            tmp.z = verts[3 * indicies[3 * i + j] + 2];
            auto found = find(points.begin(), points.end(), tmp);
            if (found == points.end()) {
                points.push_back(tmp);
                p = (PointEntry *)&(*(find(points.begin(), points.end(), tmp)));
            }
            else {
                p = (PointEntry *)&(*found);
            }
            if (p->trianglelist.capacity() < 20) {
                p->trianglelist.reserve(20);
            }
            triangle.ptidx[j] = p; 
        }
        triangle.deleted = false;
        tlist.push_front(triangle);
        std::list<TriangleData>::iterator tri = tlist.begin();
        TriangleData* t = &*tri;

        PointEntry *pt = t->ptidx[0];
        pt->trianglelist.push_back(t); ***// fails here!***

        pt = t->ptidx[1];
        pt->trianglelist.push_back(t);

        pt = t->ptidx[2];
        pt->trianglelist.push_back(t);
    }
```

The code always breaks at the point where I try to push_back my TriangleData*.
I have tried stepping through each line of code, but I have not figured out why this is happening.

Interesting thing is that when I use the **Set** data structure instead of **Vector**, the code works fine and it outputs the original model as expected.

Any advice on why I am accessing an invalid location would help, Thanks!

Comment: Why does `PointEntry` contain a `std::vector<TriangleData*>`?  That doesn't make a lot of design sense to me.

Comment: I am working on Mesh Simplification. When I load my model in, I will have a list of points and a list of triangles. But I also want a list of triangles that each point is connected to, for the simplification algorithm later on. Also storing a list of edges that are connected to the point will be useful too!

Comment: `points` is vector ?

Comment: If you are storing pointers to `vector` elements you need to know that when the `vector` grows it can reallocate memory and those pointers will no longer be valid.

Comment: Is this a [mcve]? It looks a lot longer than what i was expecting based on the question.

Comment: @rafix07: Yes, points is vector<PointEntry>, and tlist is list<TriangleData>

Comment: @TimRandall I have a version using Set data structure that I have verified. Same code, except that I have to use insert() instead of push_back, and I do not need to check for duplicates.

Comment: @Blastfurnace: If you say "those pointers will no longer be valid", are you implying I should not store pointers in a vector in general? Because my understanding is that a vector can grow and reallocate (thus changing iterator position for an element), but it won't alter or erase the actual values stored.

Comment: You can store pointers in a `vector`. The problem is holding on to pointers to elements in a `vector`. When the vector needs more capacity it reallocates memory and moves everything to that new memory. Those old pointers aren't automatically updated, they refer to the previous addresses. The standard says growing a `vector` can invalidate iterators, pointers, and references so that practice is fraught with peril. It works differently with a `set` because that is a very different data structure (typically a balanced tree).

Comment: Right, so I guess one way to avoid the problem is to use deep copy, or use indicies!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Interesting thing is that when I use the Set data structure instead of
>   Vector, the code works fine and it outputs the original model as
>   expected.

And this is solution to your problem, use set instead of vector.

if `points` is vector you cannot store the pointer to vector item because while calling `push_back` items of vector are reallocated, and pointers to them are invalidated.

After calling `push_back`

```
points.push_back(tmp);
```

all previous assignments to `p` like

```
p = (PointEntry *)&(*found);
```

may refer to invalid pointer.

Your program crashes because you want to access `trianglelist` member for invalid pointer

```
pt->trianglelist.push_back(t); ***// fails here!***
```

Comment: Right, I did not know that. Thanks for the knowledge.